# ASP.NET Core Passing database model to a label in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm new to ASP.NET Core and am creating an experiment project.
I'm sorry if the title is misleading in any way. I didn't know how to formulate it correctly.

I have some data that I'm getting from the database via a `form` `input` action.

I'd like to pass the data the database finds in a `label`.

I have tried setting the data as a `ViewBag` but I'm returned to `localhost:5001/Index?FirstName=John?LastName=Doe`, which doesn't show any data on the page, when doing `return View("index");`

This is the code I'm using:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> lookup(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    var civi = await _ctx.Character
        .Where(x => x.FirstName == firstName && x.LastName == lastName).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    ViewBag.fName = civi.FirstName;

    return View("index");
}
```

and in my view

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">@ViewBag.fName</label>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is the name of the view you have provided code for?

Comment: it's 'index'. I realized I put "Page" in the example URL as it can be misleading. I edited it.

Comment: You are calling a method that is called lookup. But in the url you provided it says Index. What is the name of the controller? Also if you put breakpoint in the method you provided are you hitting it?

Comment: I wasn't hitting the breakpoint because my dumbass self put the asp-action of the form as index instead of lookup ahaha. Thanks for assistance

Comment: I feel like I'm genuinely blind sometimes

Comment: Well it happens, debugging the code is always helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had was me not using the right action in the form.